# input batch_size does not match target batch_size when fine-tuning AutoModelForCausalLM

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, fine-tuning, huggingface-trainer

I would like to fine-tune a model to do the following task: given an input text, return relevant labels that describe it. One example might be applying labels to stack overflow questions--the key points here are that there are many labels (on the order of tens of thousands) and multiple labels can be used to classify to a given input. I would like to use MPT-7B for this task.

From my research about this problem, it seemed that the best options would be a Sequence-to-Sequence model or a Sequence Classification model, however since I want to use MPT-7B, my understanding is that I am limited to using a Causal LM model.

As a first pass, I've been trying to adapt the code in the Hugging Face [Causal Language Modeling](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/language_modeling) explainer to function in a manner similar to my task--my thinking being that if I can fine-tune the model in this example to accept the ELI5 question as input and generate an ELI5 answer as output, I can then transition to building out my classification use-case.

The first approach I tried taking resulted in this code:

```py
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, TrainingArguments, Trainer



eli5 = load_dataset("eli5", split="train_asks[:5000]")
eli5 = eli5.train_test_split(test_size=0.2)

block_size = 1024

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("distilgpt2", 
                                          padding='max_length', 
                                          truncation=True, 
                                          max_length=block_size)

def preprocess_function(examples):
    # use the question as the text, and the first answer as the target
    return tokenizer(text=[" ".join([x[0], x[1]]) for x in zip(examples["title"], 
                                                               examples["selftext"])], 
                     text_target=[x["text"][0] for x in examples["answers"]])

tokenized_eli5 = eli5.map(
    preprocess_function,
    batched=True,
    num_proc=4,
    remove_columns=eli5["train"].column_names,
)


def group_texts(examples):
    examples["input_ids"] = [x[0:block_size] for x in examples["input_ids"]]
    examples["labels"] = [x[0:block_size] for x in examples["labels"]]
    return examples

lm_dataset = tokenized_eli5.map(group_texts, batched=True, num_proc=4)

from transformers import DataCollatorForSeq2Seq

tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
# This was originally a DataCollatorForLanguageModeling but since I'm 
# essentially performing a Seq2Seq task, I thought the 
# DataCollatorForSeq2Seq might be a better option, but maybe this is
# what is causing my issues. 
data_collator = DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(tokenizer=tokenizer)

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("distilgpt2")

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="my_awesome_eli5_clm-model",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    weight_decay=0.01,
)
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=lm_dataset["train"],
    eval_dataset=lm_dataset["test"],
    data_collator=data_collator,
)
```

This results in the following trace:

```
│ in <cell line: 1>:1                                                                              │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1645 in train                    │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1642 │   │   inner_training_loop = find_executable_batch_size(                                 │
│   1643 │   │   │   self._inner_training_loop, self._train_batch_size, args.auto_find_batch_size  │
│   1644 │   │   )                                                                                 │
│ ❱ 1645 │   │   return inner_training_loop(                                                       │
│   1646 │   │   │   args=args,                                                                    │
│   1647 │   │   │   resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,                                │
│   1648 │   │   │   trial=trial,                                                                  │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1938 in _inner_training_loop     │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1935 │   │   │   │   │   self.control = self.callback_handler.on_step_begin(args, self.state,  │
│   1936 │   │   │   │                                                                             │
│   1937 │   │   │   │   with self.accelerator.accumulate(model):                                  │
│ ❱ 1938 │   │   │   │   │   tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)                      │
│   1939 │   │   │   │                                                                             │
│   1940 │   │   │   │   if (                                                                      │
│   1941 │   │   │   │   │   args.logging_nan_inf_filter                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2759 in training_step            │
│                                                                                                  │
│   2756 │   │   │   return loss_mb.reduce_mean().detach().to(self.args.device)                    │
│   2757 │   │                                                                                     │
│   2758 │   │   with self.compute_loss_context_manager():                                         │
│ ❱ 2759 │   │   │   loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)                                       │
│   2760 │   │                                                                                     │
│   2761 │   │   if self.args.n_gpu > 1:                                                           │
│   2762 │   │   │   loss = loss.mean()  # mean() to average on multi-gpu parallel training        │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2784 in compute_loss             │
│                                                                                                  │
│   2781 │   │   │   labels = inputs.pop("labels")                                                 │
│   2782 │   │   else:                                                                             │
│   2783 │   │   │   labels = None                                                                 │
│ ❱ 2784 │   │   outputs = model(**inputs)                                                         │
│   2785 │   │   # Save past state if it exists                                                    │
│   2786 │   │   # TODO: this needs to be fixed and made cleaner later.                            │
│   2787 │   │   if self.args.past_index >= 0:                                                     │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501 in _call_impl            │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1498 │   │   if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks   │
│   1499 │   │   │   │   or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks                   │
│   1500 │   │   │   │   or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):                   │
│ ❱ 1501 │   │   │   return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)                                          │
│   1502 │   │   # Do not call functions when jit is used                                          │
│   1503 │   │   full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []                             │
│   1504 │   │   backward_pre_hooks = []                                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/gpt2/modeling_gpt2.py:1113 in        │
│ forward                                                                                          │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1110 │   │   │   shift_labels = labels[..., 1:].contiguous()                                   │
│   1111 │   │   │   # Flatten the tokens                                                          │
│   1112 │   │   │   loss_fct = CrossEntropyLoss()                                                 │
│ ❱ 1113 │   │   │   loss = loss_fct(shift_logits.view(-1, shift_logits.size(-1)), shift_labels.v  │
│   1114 │   │                                                                                     │
│   1115 │   │   if not return_dict:                                                               │
│   1116 │   │   │   output = (lm_logits,) + transformer_outputs[1:]                               │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501 in _call_impl            │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1498 │   │   if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks   │
│   1499 │   │   │   │   or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks                   │
│   1500 │   │   │   │   or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):                   │
│ ❱ 1501 │   │   │   return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)                                          │
│   1502 │   │   # Do not call functions when jit is used                                          │
│   1503 │   │   full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []                             │
│   1504 │   │   backward_pre_hooks = []                                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py:1174 in forward                 │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1171 │   │   self.label_smoothing = label_smoothing                                            │
│   1172 │                                                                                         │
│   1173 │   def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:                           │
│ ❱ 1174 │   │   return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,                         │
│   1175 │   │   │   │   │   │   │      ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction,  │
│   1176 │   │   │   │   │   │   │      label_smoothing=self.label_smoothing)                      │
│   1177                                                                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:3029 in cross_entropy             │
│                                                                                                  │
│   3026 │   │   )                                                                                 │
│   3027 │   if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:                                    │
│   3028 │   │   reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)                    │
│ ❱ 3029 │   return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(re  │
│   3030                                                                                           │
│   3031                                                                                           │
│   3032 def binary_cross_entropy(                                                                 │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
ValueError: Expected input batch_size (1896) to match target batch_size (1808).
```

I suspect that this has something to do with me misusing the `AutoModelForCausalLM` or else the `DataCollatorForSeq2Seq`. Some things that come to mind as potential issues:

- The HuggingFace colab says " What's cool about language modeling tasks is you don't need labels (also known as an unsupervised task) because the next word *is* the label." but I'm trying to set labels when preprocessing the data.
- The `DataCollatorForSeq2Seq` is probably incompatible with the `AutoModelForCausalLM` in some way.

Any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong (or if there is a better way to approach my task altogether) would be very helpful.